# Преобразование строки в json

Tags: ajax, json

Как преобразовать обычную строку например

```
{"param1":"any","param2":"string"}
```

в json формат в jquery ? Я эту строку передаю php скриптом js скрипту и мне нужно снова её преобразовать что бы снова же отправить ajax-ом обратно на php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSON.parse('{"param1":"any","param2":"string"}');
```

Документация по [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: Спасибо. Будьте любезны, подскажите, как в php принять это как $_POST["param1"] и $_POST["param2"] или как их принимать? не нашёл сам.

Comment: @Владимир: Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/bhukpdf7/).

Comment: В этом я уже разобрался, а вот как принять мне нужный параметр в php если я снова передам этот json?

Comment: @Владимир: `json_decode('{"param1":"any","param2":"string"}', true)` Смотрите [результат](http://ideone.com/0loV5S).

Comment: @Владимир: Если в php значения приходят в json формате, то необходимо читать поток: `$body = trim(file_get_contents('php://input')); $result = json_decode($body, true); var_dump($result);`

Comment: @Владимир: Если нет желание разбираться почему так, то можно отправлять на сервер данные в виде сериализованной строки. Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/bhukpdf7/2/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, что бы я без Вас делал)